# sequelize association - order is not associated to user

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

In a shopping cart management system,
User has manyOrders and an order belongsTo a user, in this case userID(PK of 'User' Table) is FK in 'Order' table.
I tried this but this gives association error that order is not associated to user.

```
 db.user.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: db.order
      }
    ]
  })
    .then(users => {
      res.json(users)
    });
```

Here are the models :-

Order :-

```
'use strict';
var db = require('../models/index');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var order = sequelize.define('order', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    totalAmount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
    ,
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          order.belongsTo(models.user);
          order.belongsToMany(models.products, { through: { model: models.orderProduct } });
          // order.hasMany(models.orderProduct);
        }
      }
    });
  return order;
};
```

User :-

```
'use strict';
var db = require('../models/index');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    contact: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
  }, {
      activated: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true
      }
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          user.hasMany(models.order);
        }
      }
    });
  return user;
};
```

Here is the error :-

```
Unhandled rejection Error: order is not associated to user!
    at Model.validateIncludedElement (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:558:11)
    at F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:440:29
    at Array.map (native)
    at Model.validateIncludedElements (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:436:37)
    at Model.<anonymous> (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1372:32)
    at Model.tryCatcher (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (F:\UNI\BSCS -VII\IAD\WebProjects\Project\SERVER\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your foreign keys. Those keys you are using won't be automagically deduced.

```
order.belongsTo(models.user, {foreignKey: 'userID'});
..
user.hasMany(models.order, {foreignKey: 'userID'});
```

EDIT: I rechecked your post, your user is defined in the wrong way. Your last field "activated" is outside, closing the previous object. That's why it's not reading your association.

```
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
  }, {
      activated: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true
      }
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          user.hasMany(models.order);
        }
      }
    });
```

Should be:

```
        updatedAt: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
          allowNull: true
        },
        activated: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: true
          }
      }, {
          classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
              user.hasMany(models.order);
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Check my edit. You have an error in the definition structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Modify your associations like this:

```
order.belongsTo(models.user, {as : 'User'});

user.hasMany(models.order, {as : 'Orders'});
```

And while querying:

```
db.user.findAll({
include: [{model: db.order, as: 'Orders'}]
})
.then(users => {
  res.json(users)
});
```

Comment: problem was in my user.js (activated attribute), thanks anyways :)